# How to fix no highlight for "async" "await" keywords | VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

For some reason `async` and `await` keywords are not highlighted. "Python" and "Python for VSCode" are installed and globally enabled. I even tried to install "MagicPython" but it did not make a difference

Linter successfully detects errors such as "await allowed only with async function" (check the image below)

[image]

Comment: try a few different color themes as well, the language files might provide the scopes and tokens, but it's still up to the theme to use them. (You can inspect the scopes with the "Developer: Inspect editor scopes and tokens" command, to check if the scopes are there. It should probably be like "keyword.control.python" or similar for the async/await)

Answer (score 6):

It's may be caused by some extension you have installed.
In my situation, I disabled the "Python for VSCode" extension and reload vscode, it worked.

Comment: Is there a better extension in 2022?